# Jtextfield tooltip update before text is committed

Tags: java, swing

I have this situation, where I would like to display a number in figures. The number will be entered onto a Jtextfield and I would like the tooltip to display the amount in figures. The problem is, the tooltip displays the older data.

I have written some code to show you the issue:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class Test
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JTextField tf=new JTextField(30);
    frame.add(tf);
    frame.add(new JTextField(30));

    tf.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            tf.setToolTipText(tf.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            tf.setToolTipText(tf.getText());
        }
    });

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Let's take this situation, the user is typing number onto the first textfield. The text cursor is still on the same textfield. When the user now moves the mouse pointer over the first textfield, the tooltip is still displaying the old text. 
Now when you shift the focus to the second textfield, the first textfield's data gets committed so the tooltip also refreshes.

Now how do I display the tooltip on the text that is still not committed in a textfield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to update the tooltips each time the user types something, you should add a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) to the [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) of your `JTextField`, which can be retrieved using the [`JTextField#getDocument`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getDocument%28%29).

The [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) has an example of such a `DocumentListener`

Answer (score 4):

you can't catch this event from `Focus`, because they are invoked from `focusLost / focusGained`, simple remove these two methods and add `MouseListener`, if you want to change `JToolTip`'s text dynamically

1) define `ToolTipManager`

```
ToolTipManager ttm = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance();
ttm.setInitialDelay(0);
ttm.setDismissDelay(10000);
```

2) wrap that to the `invokeLater` for removing freeze or flickering

```
tf.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                tf.setToolTipText(tf.getText());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution works too. Could you tell me the difference between adding a Document Listener and a Mouse Listener? When does the change of text on the jtextfield actually commit?

Comment: from DocumentListener are events generated always when are there some changes, from MouseListener are events generated always onmouseEntered event

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the tooltip on the changedUpdate event of the document object of your text field:

```
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        tf.setToolTipText(tf.getText());
    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            tf.setToolTipText(tf.getText());
    }
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            tf.setToolTipText(tf.getText());
    }
});
```

Comment: A Jtextfield does not does not fire a changedUpdate event actually. Only if there were style changes this event gets fired. A plain text component only fires removeUpdate() and insertUpdate().. Thanks for the answer though..

Comment: You are welcome. You are right about the changedUpdate, but wouldn't insertUpdate solve your problem. Seeing that you have accepted an answer which is very similar to mine, I assume that you are still taking the DocumentListener approach.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `KeyListener` for the `JTextField`.

Comment: -1 Listening to changes in the input on a `JTextComponent` should happen with a `DocumentListener` on the `Document` and not with key listeners on the text field